# How to Remove 51Degrees.Mobi from project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

How do I remove 51Degrees.Mobi from my project. I was just testing it and now after trying to remove it it is throwing all kinds of errors. I want this junk out of my project.

I used Install-Package 51Degrees.Mobi to install through the package manager..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, for future reference..

Goto > Tools> NuGet Package Manager> Package Manager Console

And type Uninstall-Package 51Degrees.Mobi

After that make sure to delete all the files that it installed. There is a Mobile folder, Config files, and also remove the added text to you web.config file.

Comment: See this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980751/how-to-uninstall-specific-version-of-a-nuget-package. You have to specify the version.