# How to uninstall specific version of a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I somehow have two versions of the same NuGet package in one of my projects.

Is there a way to uninstall a specific version of that package?

I've tried `Uninstall-Package [name]` and then `Install-Package [name]`, although this seems to keep both versions.

This is causing issues in my code where references to classes in that package are being treated as ambiguous, and cause build errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus -version 3.0.1.16 -force

Comment: Using `-force` was important in this, as the package had dependencies that it had to ignore. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the version as well like

```
Uninstall-Package package_name -version specific_version
```